# AWK - OFS is not working with FS character set

Tags: awk

Is there any spell that anyone who uses awk will fail with OFS at least once?

I have the following file:

```
someone.txt

LN_A,FN_A<aa@xyz.com>;
LN_B,FN_B<bb@xyz.com>;
```

And, I need:

```
FN_A,LN_A,aa
FN_B,LN_B,bb
```

Initially, I tried the following with the below output:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt

FN_ALN_Aaa
FN_BLN_Bbb
```

After doing some research, I found that sometimes the record needs to be reconstructed. So, I tried the following, assuming changing NF will reconstruct the record.

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' 'NF=3 {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt

FN_ALN_Aaa
FN_BLN_Bbb
```

Then, I tried this:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' 'NF=3; {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt
LN_A,FN_A,aa
FN_ALN_Aaa
LN_B,FN_B,bb
FN_BLN_Bbb
```

Then, this to reconstruct the record, still no luck:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt

FN_ALN_Aaa
FN_BLN_Bbb
```

This one worked, but not as expected:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} {print $0}' someone.txt

LN_A,FN_A,aa,xyz.com>;
LN_B,FN_B,bb,xyz.com>;
```

Finally, I managed with the following:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' '{print $2 "," $1 "," $3}' someone.txt

FN_A,LN_A,aa
FN_B,LN_B,bb
```

PS:

1. I know there are many questions on the same line, but I don't think this it as a duplicate as it is not working - at least for me. :-)
2. I am using GNU Awk 3.1.7

Comment: With perl. `perl -n -e '/(.*),(.*)<(.*)@/;print "$2,$1,$3\n"' < someone.txt`

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I was trying to understand why OFS is not working in awk, in my case. Thank you for your solution though! Appreciate it.

Comment: Sure I know this doesn't answer your question, just thought another way might be of interest. I happen to know perl well and not much of awk.

Comment: No worries. Of course, It is always better to know alternate options. Thanks for your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`OFS` is generated when `print` eats a raw (unquoted) comma

I would do this:

```
$ awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=, '{print $2,$1,$3}' someone.txt

FN_A,LN_A,aa
FN_B,LN_B,bb
```

Comment: Thanks! I knew the fix would be something simple. Can you please help me understand why doesn't OFS work with {print $2 $1 $3}

Comment: `print` generates the value of `OFS` (single space by default) when it encounters an unquoted comma. If this answers your question, please consider clicking the check mark to accept it.

Comment: Also, by default, awk concatenates space-separated objects. So `$2$1$3` and `$2 $1 $3` are equivalent. Therefore, `$2, $1, $3` == `$2,$1,$3` == `$2 , $1 , $3`

Comment: Setting OFS as "-v OFS=',' " should override the default value of space, right?

Comment: Right. Try `{print $2 OFS $1 OFS $3}`, which is also equivalent

Comment: Sorry for so many questions. Purpose of OFS is to set it once so that you don't have to use it repeatedly like {print $2 OFS $1 OFS $3}, right?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192460/discussion-between-vintnes-and-acs005).

Comment: @EdMorton Seeking your help for understanding the usage of OFS. Thank you!

Comment: @acs005 OK, since you've already accepted an answer to this question maybe it's best if you just post a new followup question with it's own [mcve]. Going forward just bear in mind you don't need to accept the first answer you get to a question - it's reasonable to wait a few hours to see the selection of answers you get as the first one MAY not be the best one for you and even if it is you may get some additional information/ideas from others but as soon as you accept an answer it stops most people from even bothering to read your question never mind post another answer.

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks for your guidance, as always. I will post a follow-up question for understanding more about OFS. I accepted the answer since I thought my doubts were cleared ;-)

Comment: No problem but you might want to read https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Output-Separators and https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Changing-Fields before posting as they may clear up all your questions.

Comment: Hi! I am trying this with tabs as separators and this is not working to me:

`awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{print $1 $2}' myfile.tsv > output.tsv `

My output present no separation, the `OFS`command is not working to me.

Comment: @Jeni, use hard quotes (apostrophes): `'\t'`

Answer (score 1):

In case you are ok with `sed` could you please try following(written as per your shown samples). Using `sed`'s ability to store matched regex in memory and using it while substituting section of `sed`, since `sed` is based on `s/old/new` pattern.

```
sed 's/\([^,]*\),\([^<]*\)<\([^@]*\)\(.*\)/\2,\1,\3/'  Input_file
```