# Understanding how OFS works in AWK

Tags: awk

This is a follow-up to [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55876705/awk-ofs-is-not-working-with-fs-character-set) to understand more about the OFS in AWK.

My understanding is, set it once in the beginning and it will be used in "print" to separate the fields. However, it didn't work as expected, as explained in my original question.

My File: someone.txt

```
LN_A,FN_A<aa@xyz.com>;
LN_B,FN_B<bb@xyz.com>;
```

Expected output:

```
FN_A,LN_A,aa
FN_B,LN_B,bb
```

I have tried the following:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' 'NF=3 {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' 'NF=3; {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} {print $0}' someone.txt
```

Finally, I managed to get the required output with the following:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' '{print $2 "," $1 "," $3}' someone.txt
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider these cases:

```
a) $ echo '1 2 3' | awk '{print}'
1 2 3

b) $ echo '1 2 3' | awk '{print $1, $2, $3}'
1 2 3

c) $ echo '1 2 3' | awk -v OFS=',' '{print}'
1 2 3

d) $ echo '1 2 3' | awk -v OFS=',' '{print $1, $2, $3}'
1,2,3

e) $ echo '1 2 3' | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; print}'
1,2,3
```

The above show OFS being used in "b" and "d" (when individual fields are being printed in a comma-separated list) and in "e" (when the record $0 is being reconstructed as a result of a value being assigned to a field before the record is printed).

Those are the only 2 times when OFS is used implicitly - when printing a comma-separated list of values and when reconstructing the record.

When you print the record (e.g. by `print` or `print $0`) as in "a" and "c" above or print any other string **you are not using OFS**. OFS may have been used earlier to reconstruct the record as in "e" above but the act of printing anything that's not a comma-separated list is not using OFS, it's just printing any old string which just happens to be $0 in this case.

Note:

1. Explicitly changing a field reconstructs $0 from the existing fields using OFS between the fields, it does not resplit $0 into fields again so FS is not used in this process. So $1=$1 or sub(/1/,2,$1) uses OFS but not FS.
2. Explicitly changing $0 (i.e. not implicitly as a result of 1 above) resplits $0 into fields using FS as the separator, it does not use OFS in any way. So $0=$0 or sub(/1/,2) uses FS but not OFS.

Understanding how FS and OFS work together and how they effect assignments to fields and $0 is very important. If you can explain this behavior then you've got it:

```
f) $ echo 'a b' | awk -v OFS=',' '{print NF, $0, $1, $2}'
2,a b,a,b

g) $ echo 'a b' | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; print NF, $0, $1, $2}'
2,a,b,a,b

h) $ echo 'a b' | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; $0=$0; print NF, $0, $1, $2}'
1,a,b,a,b,

i) $ echo 'a b' | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; $0=$0; FS=OFS; print NF, $0, $1, $2}'
1,a,b,a,b,

j) $ echo 'a b' | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; $0=$0; FS=OFS; $1=$1; print NF, $0, $1, $2}'
1,a,b,a,b,

k) $ echo 'a b' | awk -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1; $0=$0; FS=OFS; $1=$1; $0=$0; print NF, $0, $1, $2}'
2,a,b,a,b
```

If not then feel free to ask questions.

Comment: Thanks for all the details but I am taking more time to make sure that I get it right. I will let you know if I have any questions once I understand all the cases mentioned above.

Comment: You're welcome, sounds good. I still sometimes have to think it through a couple of times when coding so don't worry if it's not immediately obvious! The 2 items I put in "Notes" are the most important thing to get fixed in your head - all the rest falls out of that.

Comment: Yes, those 2 points made it very clear, specifically "it does not resplit $0 into fields again". My initial understanding was wrong in thinking that when you use "$1=$1" it uses OFS to reconstruct $0 as a "field separator" between the fields(which sounds so obvious but not NOW) and hence each field is separated by OFS. Understanding that the resplit doesn't happen again is a key here.

Comment: This was a really good read, they should put these examples in the AWK tutorial :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is simple, you have set the `OFS=","` in beginning of your `awk` statement but you are simply printing the fields(NOTE: without editing the line OR without mentioning field separator(using comma etc)) in that case OFS will not come in picture that is why your output is NOT having anything like separator.

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{print $2,$1,$3}' Input_fie
```

If you use above command where I have mentioned `,` between printing fields you will see you are getting OFS now and this is how it works.

---

---

Or in case you want to see use of `OFS` you could use this(though above solution is BEST one but for your understanding I am adding this one too).

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{$0=$2 OFS $1 OFS $3} 1'  Input_file
```

---

---

***Example to understand `OFS` by printing whole line(s):*** Let us understand it more clearly by printing whole line with `OFS and without`OFS` effect.

Let us run this code:

```
awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' 'FNR==1{$1=$1} 1'  Input_file
```

What it does is when line number `1` is there then I am resetting `$1`'s value as mentioned above to let `OFS` come into picture so that new value of `OFS` comes(off course wherever field separator was picked it will place `OFS` value there). So it will only be done for first line and REST of the lines nothing should happen. Let us see what output comes now?

```
LN_A,FN_A,aa,xyz.com>;
LN_B,FN_B<bb@xyz.com>;
```

You see the difference? See first line is having `,` in output and 2nd line is printing as it is, why because in only 1st line we have edited the first field so `OFS` came into picture.

Comment: Thanks! I tried the following as well.  "awk -F'[,<@]' -v OFS=',' '{$1=$1} {print $2 $1 $3}' someone.txt". Isn't the whole record supposed to be reconstructed in this case as I am using "$1=$1"?

Comment: @acs005,yes but as I mentioned until/unless you edit the line(where new set OFS overwrites default value of OFS), let me add an example in my answer now.

Comment: @acs005, I have added 1 more explanation with example, please check it once and let me know if you have any queries here?

Answer (score 1):

As I just found an unused copy of Aho, Kernighan, Weinberger: *The AWK Programming language* from 1988, I(t)'ll take you to the source (pages 35-36):

"*Field Variables.* The fields of the current input line are called `$1`, `$2`,
through `$NF`; `$0` refers to the whole line. Fields share the properties of other
variables — they may be used in arithmetic or string operations, and may be
assigned to. - -

One can assign a new string to a field:

```
    BEGIN                          { FS = OFS = "\t" }
    $4 == "North America"          { $4 = "NA" }
    $4 == "South America"          { $4 = "SA" }
                                   { print }
```

In this program, the `BEGIN` action sets `FS`, the variable that controls the input
field separator, and `OFS`, the output field separator, both to a tab. The `print`
statement in the fourth line prints the value of `$0` after it has been modified by
previous assignments. **This is important: when `$0` is changed by assignment or
substitution, `$1`, `$2`, etc., and `NF` will be recomputed; likewise, when one of `$1`, `$2`, etc., is changed, `$0` is reconstructed using `OFS` to separate fields.**"